# Non-template type arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have this template function:

```
template<int i> void f(int a[i]) { };

int main () {
   int c[10];
   f(c); // Causes an error!
}
```

Why cant i pass `c[10]` as a non-template type argument to a template function?

Comment: You can, it's just that the parameter `int a[i]` decays into a pointer, effectively losing its size information. Therefore `i` is not being deduced when you call the function. If you called the function like `f<10>(c)` it would have worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that a function parameter that looks like an array is actually a pointer, so your template is actually equivalent to

```
template<int i> void f(int * a);
```

with no way to deduce the template argument from the function argument. You could specify it explicitly:

```
f<10>(c);
```

but that's rather error prone; a better option is to pass the array by reference, so that the template argument can be deduced:

```
template<int i> void f(int (&a)[i]);
```

Alternatively, in C++11 or later, you could use `std::array` which is a sensible object type with none of the quirks of built-in array types.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the correct function template would use `std::size_t` as template argument:

```
template<std::size_t i> void f(int (&a)[i])
```

But using an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is probably better:

```
template<std::size_t i> void f(const std::array<int, i>&)
```

You should also consider using *iterators*, if the algorithm you are developing in `f` is supposed to work with any container that provide iterators:

```
template<class It> void f(It begin, It end)
```

so that you can use your function like this:

```
int x[10]                = ...;
std::vector<int> y       = ...;
std::array<int, 10> z    = ...;

f(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
f(std::begin(y), std::end(y));
f(std::begin(z), std::end(z));
```

The latter is often used by the STL library for their container-independent algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

The prototype should be:

```
template<std::size_t N> void f(int (&a)[N]) { };
```

Note the `(&a)` syntax.

`void f(int a[N])` decays to `void f(int* a)` and we can't deduce template `N`.

`std::array` syntax looks better:

```
template<std::size_t N> void f(std::array<int, N>& a) { };
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately arrays effectively lose their size information when you pass them, so the compiler can't deduce the value of `i` from your call. A rather inelegant solution would be to explicitly specify the template argument in your call, e.g.:

```
f<10>(c);
```

Obviously that pretty much defeats the point of having a template though. A better alternative may be to use `std::array`.